# Error: Laravel Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, laravel

Creating default object from empty value

```
$w = new item;

            $w->order_id = Input::get('order_id');
            $w->user_id = Input::get('user_id');
            $w->item_id = Input::get('item_id');

            $w->save();
```

I'm trying to insert the values into w table it says me to Creating default object from empty value i don't know why object is null how to fixed it out

Comment: What's your 'model' called? You can't just use a model named 'model', as this will be the abstract Model class. Also make sure these attributes are inside the 'fillable' array in your model.

Comment: model name is item 

 protected $fillable = [
  'order_id',
  'user_id',
  'item_id',
 ];

Comment: I think your model should be Item(first letter uppercase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$w = item::create(array('order_id' => Input::get('order_id'), 'user_id' => Input::get('user_id'), 'order_id' => Input::get('item_id')));
```